# How can I change this code to SqlConnection?

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone change this code to `SqlConnection`?

```
Dim Db As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set Db = New ADODB.Connection
Db.ConnectionString = GetConnectString & AppPath & "schedule.mdb"
Call Db.Open
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = Db.Execute("select * from tbl_Schedule where StartDate = #1/1/2002#")

While Not rs.EOF
Call Me.Schedule1.ScheduleItems.Add("", #1/1/2002#, rs!StartTime, _ 
rs!Length, rs!Description, "")
Call rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: I'm sure that lots of people can perform this conversion, but StackOverflow needs you to make an attempt on your own first and then post a question about a specific problem that you have run into during the conversion.

Comment: I know my friend but if i solved this problem I will end an application after a long time and I want to use it.

Comment: You are going from Access to SQL server? Do you know the connection string? Or you are staying with Access and converting to vb.net?

Comment: Yes the connectionstring is constring

Comment: Sorry constring = "Server=" & Split(tmpStr, ":")(1) & 
                               ";Database=RDMS; Trusted_Connection=yes;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below snippet which will helps you to get data from sql database. You can alter the script with your values. Import System.Data.SqlClient namespace to work with SqlConnection

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server=.\sqlexpress;Integrated   security=sspi;database=Automation")
Dim query As String = "Select * from Heads"
If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then connection.Open()
   Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            ListBox1.Items.Add(reader("HeadName").ToString)
        End While
        reader.Close()
        connection.Close()
   End Using
```

Comment: Thank you my friend for the responce.